# ReactJS string variable cannot be used within an import(), but the same string hardcoded works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm running into something quite basic.

```
const mdLoc = "../markdowns/doc.md";
useEffect(() => {
    import(mdLoc) // yields error: Cannot find module location
```

but hardcoding the string works perfectly:

```
useEffect(() => {
    import("../markdowns/doc.md") // yields a successful import
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you should import it with `import mdLoc from "../markdowns/doc.md";`

Comment: Or `const mdLoc require("../markdowns/doc.md")`;

Comment: thanks! Number one is not an option though, because I'm actually loading it dynamically. The second solution didn't work either

Comment: Okay, if it's dynamically, you should include `await` like this `const data = await import(file).then(module => module.default);`

Comment: It's not that. There's something that changes when putting a string in a variable which breaks the import. I'd like to know what that is

Comment: Since you're using webpack, I'd look at the actual JavaScript the browser is running. Could be webpack is mangling the dynamic import statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Webpack doesn't allow you to use a dynamic value (variable) in an `import()`

https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import

> Dynamic expressions in import()
> It is not possible to use a fully dynamic import statement, such as import(foo). Because foo could potentially be any path to any file in your system or project.

> The import() must contain at least some information about where the module is located. Bundling can be limited to a specific directory or set of files so that when you are using a dynamic expression - every module that could potentially be requested on an import() call is included.

It is able to resolve an expression and and resolve all variants as a single dependent chunk to import as in the example linked:

```
const language = detectVisitorLanguage();
import(`./locale/${language}.json`).then((module) => {
  // do something with the translations
});
```

Huge warning: this import will resolve all variations into one chunk which I think is unintuitive.

> For example, import(`./locale/${language}.json`) will cause every
> .json file in the ./locale directory to be bundled into the new chunk.

I think one thing to remember is that the dynamic `import()` feature is merely function-like, and your usual considerations about function arguments and signatures do not necessarily apply to this syntax.

Just like how `import React from "react"` has specific requirements (you cannot use a variable in place of "react"), so does `import()` -- it is *not* a normal function.